# Set background color for UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, navigationbar

I want to develop `UINavigationBar` and also set background color for that. I have created the `UINavigationBar` but I have problem with setting backgroundcolor. anyone please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Try like this. I think it will be helpful to you.

Edit: updated the code to actually compile.

Comment: don't know why but Xcode doesn't popup `barTintColor` when I type it

Answer (score 15):

In the new iOs this it how it works:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle  = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor =[UIColor colorAzulNavegacion];
```

Comment: UIBarStyleBlackOpaque is deprecated in iOS 9

Answer (score 11):

I have to look this up every time so adding my answer here (Swift). The code below is setting this for all navigation bars in the app. You could set each of these on individual navigation bars too if you wanted to.

You can set the translucency, title text color, background color (this is called barTintColor, thanks, Apple!), and bar button item foreground color, like so:

```
    // Title text color Black => Text appears in white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black

    // Translucency; false == opaque
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false

    // BACKGROUND color of nav bar
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()

    // Foreground color of bar button item text, e.g. "< Back", "Done", and so on.
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: This should be selected as the best answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use the tint property of the `UINavigationBar`to change it's color. Check this [article](http://blog.whitepeaksoftware.com/2010/09/11/customizing-the-look-of-uinavigationbar-and-uinavigationcontroller/) about it. There is also `UIAppearance`, that allows you to change the background of every `UINavigationBar` of your application, which is quite powerfull in my opinion. You can check [this](http://www.ioslearner.com/uiappearance-proxy-protocol-tutorial/).

Answer (score 2):

You can set the tint color by using `navbar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];`

See the reference here: [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/tintColor)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent

Comment: Basically correct, except BlackTranslucent is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize a `UINavigationBar` with the following propertys:

- `@property(nonatomic, assign) UIBarStyle barStyle`
- `@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *tintColor`
- `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:`
- `@property(nonatomic, copy) UIColor *backgroundColor`

For more methods and propertys please check the class reference of `UINavigationBar` and `UIView`

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: Down voted because incorrect. tintColor is the color that will be used for bar button items foreground color, e.g. the "back" text, the "<" back caret, and any other button text... you want to use barTintColor to set the bg color of the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in the context of doing something useful.
In this case programmatically creating/configuring a Navigation Bar item and item and
setting the background to black and the title to light gray.

Swift 5, iOS 15

```
@objc func addButtonPushed() {
    print("Add button!")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "plus"), style: .plain,
                                      target:self, action: #selector(addButtonPushed))

    let standaloneItem     = UINavigationItem()
    standaloneItem.title   = "Herding Cats"
    standaloneItem.rightBarButtonItem  = rightButton
    navBar.items           = [standaloneItem]
    navBar.delegate        = self
    navBar.barStyle        = UIBarStyle.default
    navBar.isTranslucent   = true
    navBar.barTintColor    = .black
    navBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray]
    
    . 
    .
    .
```

}