# Stretch UINavigationBar behind status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've subclassed `UINavigationBar` to have a default, blurred image there.

I'm overriding the `drawRect:` method like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

But as you can see, the color doesn't stretch under the status bar:

[image]

Why is this? Usually, the storyboard-created bar would stretch behind the status bar.

Comment: See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061069/make-navigation-bar-stretch-behind-status-bar-in-xcode-5-ios7.  This is still applicable

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the proper way to change the `UINavigationBar` color.
Refer to [Set background color for UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114583/set-background-color-for-uinavigationbar)

Comment: How can I use UIApperance for only one UINavigationBar? Not all of them

Comment: sorry wrong link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114583/set-background-color-for-uinavigationbar

Comment: But I'm not setting the color, I need to set the background image