# UINavigationBar background color not the exact UIColor that is set it to

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am using this color code #142148.

[image]

OutPut top bar view

[image]

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:Default_blue_color];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set background color for UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114583/set-background-color-for-uinavigationbar)

Answer (score 0):

I think `tint` is just a tint, not an exact color.